# Pytorch - Iterating through a list of networks to evaluate forward time - cannot load next model

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

My code does not load the next network to evaluate, it appears to just keep evaluating the same model.

The following code is run in a directory with many sub-directories of models/networks to be evaluated for forward time on a set of image sizes.

The evaluation times recorded do not change per run of the script, however since the shuffle was added the time depends on the first model loaded.

The code performs correctly when manually doing each directory separately. when run on a set of sub-directories it repeats the test on the same network model.

'''

```
# !/usr/bin/python


import os
import numpy as np
import torch
import time
import importlib
import sys
from random import shuffle

from PIL import Image
from argparse import ArgumentParser

from torch.autograd import Variable

import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
cudnn.benchmark = True

NUM_CLASSES = 20



def getEval(args):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    modelpath = cwd + "\\" +args.loadDir + '\\' + args.loadModel + ".py"

    print ("Loading model: " + modelpath)

    MODULE_DIR = cwd + "\\" +args.loadDir + '\\' 

    print("cwd", cwd)
    sys.path.append(MODULE_DIR)
    print ("sys path", sys.path)

    model_file = importlib.import_module(args.loadModel)
    model = model_file.Net(NUM_CLASSES)

    if (not args.cpu):
        model = model.cuda()#.half()    #HALF seems to be doing slower for some reason
    #model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()

    model.eval()


    images1 = torch.randn(args.batch_size, args.num_channels, 2048, 1024)
    images2 = torch.randn(args.batch_size, args.num_channels, 1024, 512)
    images3 = torch.randn(args.batch_size, args.num_channels, 512, 256)
    images4 = torch.randn(args.batch_size, args.num_channels, 256, 256)


    images = [images1, images2, images3, images4]

    time_train = [[],[],[],[]]

    for j in range(0,4):

        inputs = Variable(images[j].cuda())

        for i in range(0,10):

            start_time = time.time()

            with torch.no_grad():
                outputs = model(inputs)

            #preds = outputs.cpu()
            if (not args.cpu):
                torch.cuda.synchronize()    #wait for cuda to finish (cuda is asynchronous!)

            if i != 0:    #first run always takes some time for setup
                fwt = time.time() - start_time
                time_train[j].append(fwt)
                print ("Forward time per img (b=%d): %.4f (Mean: %.4f)" % (args.batch_size, fwt/args.batch_size, sum(time_train[j]) / len(time_train[j]) / args.batch_size))

            time.sleep(1)   #to avoid overheating the GPU too much

    header = "2048x1024,1024x512,512x256,256x128"
    csvData = ''
    for size in range(0,4):
        csvData += '{}{:.4f}'.format("" if size == 0 else ",", sum(time_train[size]) / len(time_train[size]) / args.batch_size)
    print(header)
    print(csvData)

    # trying to clean things up from memory
    sys.path.remove(MODULE_DIR)
    del model
    del MODULE_DIR
    del model_file
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()

    return(csvData)


def main(args):
    with open('eval-win-speed.csv','w') as file:
        header = "2048x1024,1024x512,512x256,256x128"
        file.write('{},{}'.format("model_dir" ,header))
        file.write('\n')

    eval_values = []

    dirs = os.listdir(args.loadDir)
    shuffle(dirs)

    for dir in dirs:
        print(dir)

        if os.path.isdir(dir):
            print('is dir')
            class model_dir: 
                loadDir = dir
                loadModel = args.loadModel
                num_channels = args.num_channels
                batch_size = args.batch_size
                cpu = args.cpu

            eval = '{},{}\n'.format(dir, getEval(model_dir))

            with open('eval-win-speed.csv','a') as file:
                file.write(eval)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--loadDir',default="..\\trained_models\\")
    parser.add_argument('--loadWeights', default="model_best.pth")
    parser.add_argument('--loadModel', default="network")
    parser.add_argument('--num-channels', type=int, default=3)
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--cpu', action='store_true')

    main(parser.parse_args())
```

'''

expecting to record significantly different forward times for different model networks.

Comment: A bit offtopic, but isn't it simpler to execute fake forward pass before measuring time instead of computing time difference for the first run?

Comment: You might be right, Will keep this in mind. :)